# There is insufficient memory available to complete this operation

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running into an unusual problem. I have an application with a multipage that contains about 10 pages and every page contains another multipage with 3-5 pages. The problem was that the app was too "heavy" and I wanted to break it into multiple forms (a form for every page).
In the initial app the form had as I said about 10 pages, with another 3-5 pages on every one of them and on every page there were about 3-20 comboboxes, 4-40 textboxes. All of them were loaded at initialization by executing a piece of code.
Now... I copied the piece of code for every page and added it in the initializations of the form that replaced it.
The code is something like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim pagini As range
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Config")
Dim cControl As Control
Set cControl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Multipage.1", "oly", True)
    With cControl
        .Width = 650
        .Height = 380
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
    End With
Me.Controls("oly").Pages.Remove (Page1)
Me.Controls("oly").Pages.Remove (Page2)
    For Each pagini In ws1.range("pagoly")
        Me.Controls("oly").Pages.Add (pagini)
    Next pagini
i = 0
Do While i < 5
    Set cControl = Me!oly.Pages(i).Add("Forms.Frame.1", "iooly" & i, True)
        With cControl
            .Caption = "IO"
            .Width = 210
            .Height = 340
            .Top = 2
            .Left = 5
        End With
    Set cControl = Me!oly.Pages(i).Add("Forms.Frame.1", "niooly" & i, True)
        With cControl
            .Caption = "nIO"
            .Width = 210
            .Height = 340
            .Top = 2
            .Left = 220
        End With
    Set cControl = Me!oly.Pages(i).Add("Forms.Frame.1", "descriere" & i, True)
        With cControl
            .Caption = "Descriere"
            .Width = 210
            .Height = 340
            .Top = 2
            .Left = 435
        End With
Loop
End Sub
```

So far it just adds the frames on every of the 5 pages of this form. The problem is that I get the "There is insufficient memory available to complete this operation" when I want to run it and I really don't know why. Yet on the previous version which loaded 50 times more stuff there was no problem. Do you have any idea where's the problem because I really don't understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
Do While i < 5
    'stuff
Loop
```

and I don't see where i changes value so that the program will exit the loop. Am I missing something?